# Anything I try to store on database enters with value '0'

Tags: javascript, java, php, android, database

I've made a Login/Register app folowing this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxffHgiJ64M&list=PLe60o7ed8E-TztoF2K3y4VdDgT6APZ0ka

Everything was ok, but then I deleted the "age" parameter and inserted a "lastname" and a "email" parameter. So, everytime I try to register an user, the "email" field goes with value "0" (even if I dont use @ or .)

That's my Register.php file:

```html
<?php
    require("Password.php");
    $connect = mysqli_connect("x", "x", "x", "x");
    
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
     function registerUser() {
        global $connect, $name, $lastname, $email, $password;
        $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO user (name, lastname, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $name, $lastname, $email, $passwordHash);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_close($statement);     
    }
    function emailAvailable() {
        global $connect, $email;
        $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email= ?"); 
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
        $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_close($statement); 
        if ($count < 1){
            return true; 
        }else {
            return false; 
        }
    }
    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  
    if (emailAvailable()){
        registerUser();
        $response["success"] = true;  
    }
    
    echo json_encode($response);
    ?>
```

and that's my RegisterActivity.java file:

```js
package com.example.gustavo.loginregister;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final EditText edtNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNome);
        final EditText edtSobrenome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSobrenome);
        final EditText edtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        final EditText edtSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSenha);
        final Button btnRegistrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegistrar);

        btnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String name = edtNome.getText().toString();
                final String lastname = edtSobrenome.getText().toString();
                final String email = edtEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = edtSenha.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            } else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                                }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, lastname, email, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and that one is my RegisterRequest.java file:

```js
package com.example.gustavo.loginregister;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL="https://wavecheckapp.000webhostapp.com/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(String name, String lastname, String email, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("lastname", lastname);
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I've checked everything many times... There's no INT parameters, everything is STRING. The database in on utf8_unicode_ci. The name and the lastname and the password are being stored perfectly. In the database the parameters are VARCHAR type.

Answer (score 2):

Simple mistake, you've mixed up the email address field in `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` with an `i` instead of an `s`.

Change,

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $name, $lastname, $email, $passwordHash);
```

To,

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssss", $name, $lastname, $email, $passwordHash);
```

I'm unsure how `mysqli` casts the parameter to the type you have provided but when you run the following code the output is `0`:

```
<?php
echo (int) 'test@test.com'; ---> 0
?>
```

Comment: Thaanks, you saved my life. I'm kinda noob in programming in Android Studio so I really didn't know the meaning of this "ssis". Now I know, thanks to you :)

Comment: @GustavoContreiras no problem, always consult the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) first. Consider accepting my answer if it helped.