# E/Volley: [145] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for https://

Tags: javascript, java, php, android

My first thread: [Anything I try to store on database enters with value '0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156258/anything-i-try-to-store-on-database-enters-with-value-0/46161402?noredirect=1#comment79285678_46161402)

I solved that, but now I'm having another problem:
Why am I having this error when I try to login?

```
09-11 17:20:46.382 2577-5031/com.example.gustavo.loginregister D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
09-11 17:20:47.415 2577-5031/com.example.gustavo.loginregister E/Volley: [145] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for https://xxxxxxx.000webhostapp.com/Login.php
09-11 17:22:39.640 2577-6700/com.example.gustavo.loginregister E/Volley: [152] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for https://xxxxxxx.000webhostapp.com/Login.php
```

LoginActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.gustavo.loginregister;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final EditText edtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        final EditText edtSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSenha);
        final Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        final TextView txtCadastreSe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCadastreSe);

        txtCadastreSe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent registroIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registroIntent);
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String email = edtEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = edtSenha.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success) {
                                String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                                String lastname = jsonResponse.getString("lastname");

                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                intent.putExtra("lastname", lastname);
                                intent.putExtra("email", email);
                                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(email, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

LoginRequest.java file:

```js
package com.example.gustavo.loginregister;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL="https://wavecheck.000webhostapp.com/Login.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public LoginRequest(String email, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Login.php file:

```html
<?php
    require("Password.php");
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxxx");
    
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $colUserID, $colName, $colLastname, $colEmail, $colPassword);
    
    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  
    
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        if (password_verify($password, $colPassword)) {
            $response["success"] = true;  
            $response["name"] = $colName;
            $response["lastname"] = $colLastname;
            $response["email"] = $colEmail;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you visit https://wavecheck.000webhostapp.com/Login.php directly it doesn't return JSON. It returns a 404 error page "There's nothing here, yet.
This domain is ready to be registered.". This is a message from the host. Apparently you're using a FREE host, and the "wavecheck" subdomain isn't there. So you'd need to re-host your PHP script, or get in contact with the free host to figure out what happened.

Comment: URL blocked by Avast when I try accessing it, could be OP also has an AV blocking it. But yeah, it looks like its down.

Comment: Has nothing to do with Avast. Don't complicate matters because he's accessing it through Java which doesn't run through Avast.

Comment: The webshield still checks all outgoing and incoming connections, if it's accessed through Java or a browser doesn't matter. The point being an AV can block it. If it gives a 404 though, that doesn't matter

Comment: Still not worth mentioning. Avast or not, there's bigger problems to be dealt with namely his FREE host pulled the plug on his subdomain.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'd never solve that alone. There's an option in the free web hosting site to register domain. I'll try that. I'll try to delete and upload the files again, cause at the moment I was just editing the files online.

Comment: @GustavoContreiras I'd contact the host and find out what happened so mistakes aren't repeated. Perhaps it broke their terms of service or something.

Comment: @LunarWatcher There's no reason to think he's running Avast on his phone.

Comment: I think the error was because the site name is "wavecheckapp.com" not "wavecheck.com"... oh my god thats embarrassing. Now I can login. Sometimes when you are programming for hours you let this mistakes happen :/